# How to auto-deploy compute task without placing jar in cluster node using thin client

Tags: java, ignite, thin-client

We upgraded to ignite2.10.0 latest version. And trying to launch compute tasks using thin client configuration.

**Problem**: I have to place jar everytime in cluster node whenever i changed a single line of code

Is there any way i can execute tasks dymanically (auto-deploy) without placing jar in cluster node?

Your response will be greatly appericated

Answer (score 4):

It's not possible to deploy tasks dynamically (like using peerClassLoading) for thin clients yet. For now, you need to have the tasks deployed before calling them.

More details: https://ignite.apache.org/docs/latest/thin-clients/java-thin-client#executing-compute-tasks

Alternatively, you might check the following docs regarding [UriDeploymentSpi](https://ignite.apache.org/docs/latest/code-deployment/deploying-user-code). In short, instead of manually updating the jars, you might set a local folder or URI that the cluster will check from time to time and deploy a new version of code if available.